# Does matrix multiplication distribute over blocks?

Tags: matrices

Does matrix multiplication distribute over blocks?

In other words, does $A[B|C] = [AB|AC]$? And does this generalizes to a block partition that is more than one block tall? That is does
$$
X
\begin{bmatrix}
    A & B & \\
    D & C & 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    XA & XB & \\
    XD & XC & 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(Note the written out matrix is a block matrix; I just didn't figure out how to draw lines between the blocks in latex.)

I believe that the column situation is true, but I am less confident about the 2D block case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for $A[B|C]=[AB|AC]$. This is due in definition of of multiplication say $D=EF$, $D_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n E_{ik}F_{kj}$, here $F_{kj}$ just involves elements from the $j$ columns and not any other columns.

The block matrix case is not a valid multiplication.

Suppose $A$ and $D$ both have $n$ rows each, then on the left hand side $X$ has $2n$ columns, but on the right hand side $X$ has $n$ columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the matrix product to be defined, there are constraints on the dimensions of the matrices involved. It's easy to see that these constraints fail in the second case.